# Unit test $in in mongoose unit test

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have a call,

```
const searchQueryWithServiceItem = { createdBy: queryParams.createdBy, tagArray: { $in: [queryParams.tag] }};
```

after that `userTags.paginate(searchQueryWithServiceItem, paginationParams)`

this test is failing. But if I remove **$in** from tagArray it is passed.

Please help. I am using mocha + chai

Comment: is `queryParams.tag` a string?

Comment: Its comma separated string.  But my point is normal code is working fine, only UT fails